# Replacing a line in a file based on a keyword search, by line from another file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my file1:

> **agadfad
>
>   sdffasdf
>
>   Element 1, 0, 0, 0
>
>   Pcom
>
>   Element 2**

Here is my file2:

> **PBAR
>
>   Element 1, 100, 200, 300, 400
>
>   Element 2
>
>   Continue...**

I want to search with a keyword, "Element 1" in file1, if found store the whole line; then search in file2, if found at some line, replace it with the data from file1 which is in this case "Element 1,0,0,0". Similarly, if there are more keywords like "Element 2, Element 3 and so on...", and the files are very big, it should do the same (But this part comes later). I tried following code:

```
    index1 = 0
    index2 = 0
    path1 = "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\BDF1.TXT"
    path2 = "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\BDF2.TXT"
    Target = 'Element 1'
    with open(path1) as f1:
       list1 = f1.readlines()
       for line in list1:
           index1 = index1 + 1
           if Target in line:
               print "Match Found at line %d" %(index)
           else:
               print "No Match Found in the target file!"
           with open(path2, "r+") as f2:
               list2 = f2.readlines()
               for line2 in list2:
                   index2 = index2 + 1
                   if Target in line2:
                        list2[index2] = line + '                    \n'
                   else:
                        print "No match found in the targetorg file!"
               f2.writelines(list2)
```

I am getting some output which looks like this:

> **PBAR
>
>   Element 1, 100, 200, 300, 400
>
>   Element 2
>
>   Continue... 
>   PBAR
>
>   Element 1, 100, 200, 300, 400
>
>   agadfad
>
>   Continue...**

And i am also getting error `list assignment index out of range` at somewhere line 20. It seems easier, but having hard time to figure it out.

Comment: In your actual files, does the string you're trying to match always start with "Element" and followed by an integer? And is it always the case that "Element N" is either the end of the line or followed by a comma?

Comment: @Reti43 Yes it'll always be starting with "Element" followed by a space and then the integer and then the comma. That's why i made it keyword for searching. And it'll always be in starting of line.

Comment: Will there always be a comma? "Element 2" in your example isn't followed by anything.

Comment: @Reti43 Sorry my mistake, i forgot to put something there, actually it's an example file. And to your question yes, it'll (,) always be there followed by some data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) will do what you want easily, assuming the format is always the same. That is each line has the format "Element N, *more stuff*", where

- "Element N" is always capitalised, followed by a space and then only numbers
- *more stuff* is consisted of only spaces, commas and numbers.

**Code**

```
import re

with open(path1) as f1, open(path2) as f2:
    dat1 = f1.read()
    dat2 = f2.read()

    matches = re.findall('^Element [0-9]+,[0-9, ]+', dat1, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    for match in matches:
        dat2 = re.sub('^{},[0-9, ]+'.format(match.split(',')[0]), match, dat2, flags=re.MULTILINE)

with open('changed.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(dat2)
```

**Explanation**

The pattern `"^Element [0-9]+,[0-9, ]+"` starts at the beginning of a line (because of ^), and matches the string Element, followed by a space, followed by any length of numbers ([0-9]+), followed by a comma, followed by any length of a combination of numbers, commas and spaces ([0-9, ]+). The will effectively find "Element 1, 0, 0, 0", "Element 2, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123" (for example), etc.

Then you iterate through these matches, search for a string that matches "Element 1,[0-9, ]+" (and so on) in the second file and substitute it for the match from the first file.

Comment: Hey @Reti43 i tried running this code, but nothing is going on. may i know is it because we're giving search phrase as "^Element [0-9]+,[0-9, ]+" where [0-9] is the range of integers, while in a file everything is treated as string???

Comment: Reti, i have another doubt, suppose my pattern is like "Element     1     5     6     7      0" which is not having any comma, how i can do so.

Comment: @Divyanshu Then, assuming you're still searching for Element 1, the pattern for `findall()` will be `"^Element [0-9]+ [0-9 ]+"` and the pattern for `sub()` will be `"^{} [0-9 ]+"`. Basically, the only thing that changes is `[0-9, ]+` to `[0-9 ]+`, which will search for numbers and spaces, but no commas.

Comment: I came up with little problem again, i implemented the code in real file which is:                                                                                                       PBUSH    5       K      539224. 257374.         4.6385+62.214+6
                 RCV    1.      1.      1.      1.   and in findall i wrote '^PBUSH [0-9]+ K [0-9 ]+' and in sub ('^{} [0-9 ]+'.format(match.split(' ')[1]) i don't know why its not working.

Comment: here "PBUSH 5" is the search keyword with random number of spaces, and then "K" and then spaces, and then some decimals. RCV is at second line, we don't need to do anything with it. And every line starting with PBUSH will have "K" written after an integer, which is an integer and continuously increasing upto some 10000...

Comment: Hey, can you please look into further problem i am facing.. Here is the link to complete description http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157386/how-to-write-correct-regex-format-for-finding-and-replacing-lines-in-a-file