# Use findall and sub functions from regex to search and replace exact string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Based on this forum [Replacing a line in a file based on a keyword search, by line from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656477/replacing-a-line-in-a-file-based-on-a-keyword-search-by-line-from-another-file/34658124#34658124) i am having little difficulty in my real file. Where as shown in picture below, i want to search a keyword "PBUSH followed by number(keeps increasing)" and based on that keyword i'd search in the other file if it is present or not. If it is present then replace the data from the line "PBUSH number K Some decimals" to the found line in another file, keeping search keyword as same. It'll keep going till the end of file,  which looks like [image]

and the code i modified (notice the findall and sub format) looks like:

```
import re
path1 = "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PBUSH1.BDF"
path2 = "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PBUSH2.BDF"

with open(path1) as f1, open(path2) as f2:
    dat1 = f1.read()
    dat2 = f2.read()

    matches = re.findall('^PBUSH \s [0-9] \s K [0-9 ]+', dat1, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    for match in matches:
        dat2 = re.sub('^{} \s [0-9] \s K \s'.format(match.split(' ')[0]), match, dat2, flags=re.MULTILINE)

with open(path2, 'w') as f:
    f.write(dat2)
```

Here my search keyword is PBUSH spaces Number and then the rest follows as shown in the PBUSH lines. I am unable to make it work. What could be the possible reason!

Comment: Please post text as text, not as picture

Comment: I think you want to use `\s+` instead of ` \s ` -- e.g. `^PBUSH\s+[0-9]...`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Hi Andrea, thanx for quick response. I'll surely consider that next time onward. As per your suggestion, it's giving output but not exactly. some random numbers are coming in those lines.

Comment: I can't give you an exact solution, as you have not specified the exact output you expect

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini If you goto the last forum (link attached) you'll find what i am looking for. Since, explaining the whole requirement will be inappropriate. I attached it. Anyways, here i am searching a keyword "PBUSH    Number" and if found the same in other file, replace the whole line from file 1 to file 2. As you can see in the pic above, only the PBUSH line should be replaced in the other file which looks like the same but with different data following "K".

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not going to read all that text (and I know many other people are not going to read it too). If you want to increase the chances of getting an answer, provide the expected output for the given input

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Hey i am sorry. But now i edited the question. Please notice, that based on "PBUSH 5" keyword, i am gonna copy the data on that particular line from one file and replace the same data in another file at the particular location where the search keyword is found. I am having difficulty only in correct formatting in findall() and sub(). Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use groups in such case and separate the whole string into two, one for matching phrase and other for data.

```
import re
# must use raw strings for paths, otherwise we need to
# escape \ characters
input1 = r"C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PBUSH1.BDF" 
input2 = r"C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PBUSH2.BDF"

with open(input1) as f1, open(input2) as f2:
    dat1 = f1.read()
    dat2 = f2.read()

# use finditer instead of findall so that we will get 
# a match object for each match.
# For each matching line we also have one subgroup, containing the
# "PBUSH   NNN     " part, whereas the whole regex matches until
# the next end of line
matches = re.finditer('^(PBUSH\s+[0-9]+\s+).*$', dat1, flags=re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    # for each match we construct a regex that looks like
    # "^PBUSH   123      .*$", then replace all matches thereof
    # with the contents of the whole line
    dat2 = re.sub('^{}.*$'.format(match.group(1)), match.group(0), dat2, flags=re.MULTILINE)

with open(input2, 'w') as outf:
    outf.write(dat2)
```