# How to write correct regex format for finding and replacing lines in a file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have got two files, and both of them looks like (Except the data after K in each line starting only with PBUSH in both the files ) :

```
$ Elements and Element Properties for region : RFAST_BUSH_CID_1.a.r1.r1.    
$ .r1    
PBUSH    9       K      435008.         522649. 6.8198+6        8.1938+6    
                 RCV    1.      1.      1.      1.    
$ Pset: "RFAST_BUSH_CID_1.a.r1.r1..r1" will be imported as: "pbush.9"    
CBUSH    1207216 9       1014816 100670                          1
        .5     
$ Elements and Element Properties for region : RFAST_BUSH_CID_1.b.r1.r1.    
$ .r1    
PBUSH    10      K      319265.         148977. 988690.         461348.    
                 RCV    1.      1.      1.      1.     
$ Pset: "RFAST_BUSH_CID_1.b.r1.r1..r1" will be imported as: "pbush.10"    
CBUSH    1207615 10      1016116 800007                          1 
        .5    
$ Elements and Element Properties for region : RFAST_BUSH_CID_12.r1.r1.r    
PBUSH    11      K      311773.         341027. 2.4204+6        2.6475+6    
                 RCV    1.      1.      1.      1.    
$ Pset: "RFAST_BUSH_CID_12.r1.r1.r" will be imported as: "pbush.11"    
CBUSH    1208216 11      1017412 100781                          0
        .5    
$ Elements and Element Properties for region : pbush.6284.r1.r1.r1.r1.r1    
PBUSH    6284    K      496800.         496799. 9.6155+6        9.6154+6    
                 RCV    1.      1.      1.      1.     
$ Pset: "pbush.6284.r1.r1.r1.r1.r1" will be imported as: "pbush.6284"    
CBUSH    1206132 6284    1012231 101532                          1
        .5    
$ Elements and Element Properties for region : pbush.6286.r1.r1.r1.r1.r1    
PBUSH    6286    K      496800.         496799. 9.6155+6        9.6154+6    
                 RCV    1.      1.      1.      1.
```

So, suppose this is my source file, from which i need to search for all the lines starting with PBUSH(which will remain same) followed by spaces followed by Number(Which is changing throughout as shown in image.) and check if it is present in the target file based on keyword, "PBUSH   Number". If found in target file, need to replace data after "K" from source to target file at the exact line where it is found. So, it need to iterate through all the lines in source and target file till the end. Now i got something working with the following code:

```
import re
path1 = "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PBUSH1.BDF"
path2 = "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PBUSH2.BDF"

with open(path1) as f1, open(path2) as f2:
    dat1 = f1.read()
    dat2 = f2.read()

    matches = re.findall('^PBUSH\s+[0-9]\s+[0-9 ]+', dat1, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    for match in matches:
        dat2 = re.sub('^{}\s+[0-9]\s+'.format(match.split(' ')[0]), match, dat2, flags=re.MULTILINE)

with open(path2, 'w') as f:
    f.write(dat2)
```

I am having difficulty in getting the exact output as what i am looking for. My format at findall and sub seems wrong. Do i need to use something for decimals? Right now nothing is being changed in the target file. I am continuously varying the formats to check which suits here..

Comment: Can you please place the example contents in text form, rather than image form?

Comment: @JordanPilat Hey i am sorry, but i was looking for this option of attaching text everywhere, i didn't find one. Can you please help me with that>

Comment: @JordanPilat Hey, I replaced image with the text. Is it okay?

Comment: For starters, `'^PBUSH\s+[0-9]\s+[0-9 ]+'` only matches single-digit numbers after `PBUSH`, and it can only match digits or spaces afterwards, although there are other characters there - to match the whole line, use `'^PBUSH\s+[0-9]+\s+.*'`

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks for reply. I'll check that, but what about format at sub(). Is it correct? and also the delimiter and number in split function? Does it seems right to you?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Hey Tim, i tried to use that but there is no change in target file. Is it because of Sub() format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general case one would parse and write the BDF files with something like the [pyNastran](http://pynastran-git.readthedocs.org/en/v0.7.2/manual/index.html).

---

However in this specific case using your approach is not that wrong; though your regular expressions are wrong, though the principle works here. Notice also, you need to use raw strings or escape `\` in the paths; the use of unescaped `\` is being deprecated and can lead to hard-to-find errors.

```
import re

# must use raw strings for paths, otherwise we need to
# escape \ characters
input1 = r"C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PBUSH1.BDF"
input2 = r"C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PBUSH2.BDF"

output = r"C:\Users\sony\Desktop\OUTPUT.BDF"

with open(path1) as f1, open(path2) as f2:
    dat1 = f1.read()
    dat2 = f2.read()

# use finditer instead of findall so that we will get 
# a match object for each match.
#
# For each matching line we also have one subgroup, containing the
# "PBUSH   NNN     " part, whereas the whole regex matches until
# the next end of line
matches = re.finditer('^(PBUSH\s+[0-9]+\s+).*$', dat1, flags=re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    # for each match we construct a regex that looks like
    # "^PBUSH   123      .*$", then replace all matches thereof
    # with the contents of the whole line
    dat2 = re.sub('^{}.*$'.format(match.group(1)), match.group(0), dat2, flags=re.MULTILINE)

with open(output) as outf:
    outf.write(dat2)
```

Comment: Thank you Antti, i'll check that and let you know if i face any problem. I'll also consider using pyNastran module.

Comment: But my question is, if number in finditer becomes double digit or triple, will it work properly? Because [0-9] considers only single digit number, doesn't it?

Comment: @Divyanshu you're correct, I added the missing `+`. This also assumes that the fields are always aligned.

Comment: Thank you Antti. And here Group means We're dividing the whole string to  two parts, one for matching keyword, another for replacing the data. If i am not wrong!

Comment: Thank you Antti code worked fine after i made some changes with file names and output file was not needed, as i had to replace the target file.